# How to add a sum of sines with general form $\frac{(4n-2)\pi}{23}$ between $1$ and $11$?

Tags: trigonometry, summation

The question is to solve for $x$:

$$\tan x = \sum_{n=1}^{11} \sin\frac{(4n-2)\pi}{23}$$

How do I express the above as a tangent of one angle without using a calculator

In general what is the technique to solve the above types of problems

Do I use Euler's formula?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17966/how-can-we-sum-up-sin-and-cos-series-when-the-angles-are-in-arithmetic-pro

Comment: [How to format mathematics on this site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)